# NgAdmin list all laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, ng-admin

I am using NgAdmin with Laravel to create a restAPI with an Admin structure using Angular.

Everything was okay with all the methods in the Controllers but then I needed to get all items in some specif table *(with the results not paginated)*;

```
 public function index()
{
    try{
        $statusCode = 200;
        $builder = \ApiHandler::parseMultiple($this->place, array('latitude,longitude'), $this->passParams('places'));
        $places = $builder->getResult();
        $response = [];
        foreach($places as $place){
            $response[] = [
                'id'    => $place->id,
                'latitude'  => $place->latitude,
                'longitude'  => $place->longitude,
                'updated_at' => $place->updated_at
            ];
        }

        return $this->makeResponse($response,$statusCode, $builder);
    }catch (\Exception $e){
        $statusCode = 500;
        $message = $e->getMessage();
        return \Response::json($message, $statusCode);
    }
}
```

The thing is that my `$builder` always give me a limit of `315` items and paginates the rest.

Have you guys faced the same problem?

All I want is to get `all` items.